# RegExp for limiting 2 decimal point tin Typescript

Tags: regex, string, typescript, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have the following RegExp in a directive in Angular 5 app:

```
private regex = {
        number: new RegExp(/^\d+$/),
        decimal: new RegExp(/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*){0,1}$/g) 
    };
```

Inside the event I have the following call to match:

```
if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex[this.numericType])) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

My problem is that the RegExp allow more than 2 digit after the decimal points. I have tried to remove the * and put {0,2} or {1,2} but it didn't work. Any idea what should I change in the code above to make it work with no more than 2 decimal points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd do it like this

`^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?$`

```
 ^                             # BOS
 [0-9]+                        # Required, many digits
 (?:                           # Optional group
      \. [0-9]{0,2}                 # decimal, followed by 0 - 2 digits
 )?
 $                             # EOS
```